# KSQL table group by with only one output within the given time

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, ksqldb

Hi I have created a stream with has the following values from the topic,

"id VARCHAR, src_ip VARCHAR, message VARCHAR"

Now I need to see if failed_login repeates more than 3 times in given time then raise an alert. So I have created a table as below,

```
CREATE TABLE  231_console_failure AS \
      SELECT src_ip, count(*) \ 
      FROM console_failure \
      WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 30 SECONDS) \
      WHERE message = 'failed_login' \
      GROUP BY src_ip \
      HAVING count(*) > 3;
```

Now when I use my python script to consume from the topic as '231_console_failure' then I get a None continously when there is no match

And when there is a match i.e more that 3 in 30 sec then it gives that value. But say if there are 10 attempt in 30 sec then the consumer fetches 7 messages where each message differ with count from 4 to 10.

I know I can handle this in script by avoiding the None and take only higher count in given time. But is there any way to create a stream from the above table which will have only matched messages with groupby in KSQL?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently possible in KSQL, but there is an enhancement request open if you want to upvote/track it: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1030

For now, per the same ticket, you can experiment with `cache.max.bytes.buffering` and `commit.interval.ms` to vary how often the aggregate is emmited.